# Where is the number of questions which have an open bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I used to see a number of questions which have an open bounty in [FEATURED](https://askubuntu.com/?tab=featured) tab. Now it has disappeared. Why? Again I have to do a patchwork to this site?

[image: featured tab]

Comment: Seems that you have to be in "Question" section to see it...

Comment: You seem to be finding a lot of problems with this site recently :)...

Comment: @Braiam Well, before it was there without to click "Questions"?

Comment: @RolandiXor Is this a problem? I asked why (maybe someone knows), but if it's stupid and embarrassing for someone to ask here, then please tell me how it would sound if I will ask my grandmother who never even heard about Ubuntu... Of course some people may find it useful and attractive to give more clicks :)

Comment: Radu you totally misunderstood @Rolandixor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From today, 14 sep. 2013, that number of questions which have an open bounty reappeared again in its place in the main page. It was probably went on vacation.-

Answer (score 0):

Hello as @Braiam suggests there is nothing wrong or may be there is I don't quite know. But if you want to see the number of featured questions you must first click the Questions tab then you will be able to see it :)

[image: I just learned of the beautiful Shutter :)]

Comment: Hmm. I can do it without clicking questions..

Comment: @Seth Hmm...You didn't upgrade yet at the last version of the site? :)

Comment: @mojo706 My question was referring to the main page.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I don't understand...

Comment: @Seth You don't have to... just a bad joke, sorry :)) I just wonder how you can do it...